# Can styled-components be rendered on the server as well?

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss, styled-components

is there any example demo that shows styled-components could be rendered on the server?
This is important off course for universal apps in react...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can be rendered on the server. There is an on-going discussion on server side rendering in the styled-components repo here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/124

There are a few examples in there.